# how to apply if condition for all the elements of a matrix without using nested loops in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to apply the if condition in the code without using loops. please suggest

```
BC=[1 0 5 -1 0 ];
for j=1:N_Nodes
    if BC(j)>0
        for k=1:N_Nodes                            
            if  BC(k)==0 && dist(j,k)<CS_Range && NAV(j)<packetlength
                  NAV(j)=packetlength;      
            end 
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Please, show some efforts : there are 5 undefined variables in 10 lines of code. If you want to get some help, you should make easier for us to help you

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to set every element of NAV to a packetlength, if both the BC is 0 and the current NAV is smaller than the packet length. Also the range of this operation should be CS_RANGE at max. Assuming that N_Nodes is equal to the length of BC and equal to the length of NAV (5) you may use boolean operations:

```
NAV(BC==0 & NAV<packetlength) = packetlength
```

as the packetlength does not change in the process the outer loop can be omitted anyway and therefore there is no need for any distance boundary.

If this doesn't answer your question, please define the undefined parameters in your code.